# Change height of toolbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar

I have a toolbar with an added subview which has a height of 50. The subview is working perfectly but the toolbar cuts off the bottom of the view.

I have tried changing the frame with CGRectMake but this doesn't have any effect.

Here is the code:

```
var bannerAdView: FBAdView!


    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(false)

        self.navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
        bannerAdView = FBAdView(placementID: "bannerID", adSize: kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner, rootViewController: self)
        bannerAdView.delegate = self
        navigationController?.toolbar.addSubview(bannerAdView)
        navigationController?.toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,50)
        bannerAdView.loadAd()

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit:
As Nate pointed out below, you can subclass UIToolbar and override the height to whatever custom height you want. That'd be cleaner than cloning it with a normal UIView, as you'd still get all the rest of the natural UIToolbar behaviors.

Original: unfortunately you're pretty much stuck with the typical UIToolbar height of 44.0px.

If I absolutely had to use something 50px high, I'd hide the actual toolbar and spoof it with a UIView that looks exactly like one. You might have some trouble emulating UIBarButtonItems with UIButtons, but if it's gotta be 50px high that's probably the quickest way for you to implement your UI.

Comment: I was fearing that!! The only problem is I'm adding the view to a tableViewController and I can't get the view to stick to the bottom of the screen and not move when the table view scrolls. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll just have to use a UIViewController, and embed your UITableView and UIView inside it. It shouldn't be too much trouble, and it'll allow you more customization inside your view hierarchy.


Edit: there are also hackier ways to do it, like capturing the reference to the UITableView in viewDidLoad, swapping a new UIView in for self.view and adding your tableView as a subview of the new self.view... but i wouldn't generally recommend it cuz it's wonky and the other way isn't hard. good luck :)

Comment: Not correct. You can subclass UIToolbar and change its height from the default of 44. Don't have to use a UIView (although, that's another way to do it).